# Vectorizing row-wise numpy operation

Tags: python, numpy

I'm writing a neural net from scratch and need to implement the following operation:
For each row of matrix dY, take the outer product of the same row of another matrix S (same shape as Y) with itself, and multiply that row of dY by that matrix outer(S[i,:], S[i,:]). Also multiply dY * S element-wise and add that to it.

The code below does this, but it's not vectorized. Can you help me speed this up?

```
out = dY.copy()
for i in range(dY.shape[0]):
    out[i, :] = dY[i, :] * S[i, :] - dY[i, :].dot(np.outer(S[i, :], S[i, :]))
```

Update: The following takes an (n,m) matrix `S` and returns a matrix of shape (n,m,m) where for each row, we take the outer product with itself.

```
np.einsum("ab,ad->abd", S, S)
```

Update 2: Finally solved it using two applications of np.einsum.

```
S_outer = np.einsum("ab,ad->abd", S, S)
return dY * S - np.einsum("ab,abc->ac", dY, S_outer)
```

Comment: Is this homework? (If it is, we'll avoid giving you a straight answer and help you find it on your own)

Comment: It is a homework, yes. The vectorizing is just for speed though, I've already solved the problem correctly above.

Comment: Nitpick, but consider `out = np.empty_like(dY)`. You don't need to prefill, much less copy the data.

Comment: I've posted a solution using just broadcasting. You should post your solution as an answer to. It legitimately stands on its own. I think you may not need two einsums, ill update of I figure out how.

Comment: Don't forget to select an answer by clicking on the check mark under it when you get the chance. We both get some points, and your question will no longer be in the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's break this into parts. You have

```
out[i, :] = dY[i, :] * S[i, :] - dY[i, :].dot(np.outer(S[i, :], S[i, :]))
```

Let's write it as

```
p = dY[i, :] * S[i, :]
si = S[i, :]
q = dY[i, :].dot(si[:, None] * si)
out[i, :] = p - q
```

Clearly, `p` can be factored out of the loop entirely ad `dY * S`. You can compute `q` by getting a stack of outer products shaped `(S.shape[0], S.shape[1], S.shape[1])` and applying `@`, a.k.a [`np.matmul`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html). The key is that `matmul` broadcasts all but the last two dimensions together, while [`dot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) effectively takes the outer product. That allows you to specify that `dY` is a stack of vectors rather than a matrix simply by introducing a new dimension:

```
out = dY * S - dY[:, None, :] @ (S[:, :, None] * S[:, None, :])
```

Comment: Within `q = dY[i, :].dot(s[:, None] * s)`, you mean `si` and not `s`, right?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Btw, I am also a physicist (though not of the mad variety).

Comment: @betelgeuse05. Yes. I fixed the typo. Unfortunately I sold out years ago and became an engineer :)

Answer (score 1):

Posting the solution I found as an answer as well.

You can do it with two calls to np.einsum().

```
S_outer = np.einsum("ab,ad->abd", S, S)
return dY * S - np.einsum("ab,abc->ac", dY, S_outer)
```